# Call PHP function with AJAX, but redirect doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem that is turning my head. I will explain the situation... I'm working on a project with opencart, and I created a button that works like this: when you click on it, it should send to the website owner that everything is within the shopping cart, and these products go together customer data, and only can send the email if the user is logged in, then the problem starts.

This is the button where the customer will click:

```
<div class="checkout-button"><a id="button-quotation" class="button">click me</a></div>
```

Then through the AJAX will call the PHP function to check for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button-quotation').click(function(){
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var ajaxurl = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/quotation',
    data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        alert("works!!");
    });
});});
```

And here there is a redirect function that will send the client to the login page, if it is not logged:

```
public function quotation(){
    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', 'SSL');

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')); 
    }
}
```

I can make the emails work, but I can not run the redirect if the client is not logged into the site. Someone can help me please?

Comment: Can't you just add quotation() to your click function?

Comment: you can achieve this in 2 way..Approach 1) simple way- you can perform the redirection in client side (just send a response as "loginRequired" and check this string in ajax response and redirect to login page) Approach 2) you should be send the reponse as 302 with redirection header

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect in your PHP function only the AJAX request will be redirected.

What you should do: let the function return data that indicates the JavaScript that it should issue a redirect to your login page.

See also this question: [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the url to ajax and redirect through javascript.

`window.location.href  =  response.your_login_url ;`